# lock account and sleep

Tags: macos, mac, sleep-wake, script

Is there an easy way to lock my mac and then immediately sleep, all in one command? I know I can show the login window and then choose the sleep button, but I'd prefer one step rather than two (and a wait in between). There's also the `Lock Screen` command in the Keychain menu, but that (stupidly) offers no sleep button that I can see. Could a script work for this, or would the script also get stuck after one command?

*Update:* Forgot to mention that I don't want to always have to enter my password after waking up from sleep, only after I explicitly lock the computer.

Comment: Locking implies password entry, what would be the benefit from locking otherwise?

Comment: @patrix: Daniel L. updated my question, hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: What was wrong with the question? It's always nice to get a comment when getting a downvote, otherwise how can you learn from your mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, a script containing these two commands (first one sleeps, second one suspends computer) worked fine:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to sleep'
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu\ Extras/User.menu/Contents/Resources/CGSession -suspend
```

The order is apparently not important, neither command stops the other from completing.

Sorry for not making myself clear enough (Sometimes I want to put the computer to sleep without password prompt when waking).

Answer (score 6):

<kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⏏</kbd> will put the computer to sleep. Then, if you have "Require password [immediately] after sleep or screen saver begins" checked under System Preferences ➔ Security ➔ General, it will prompt you for a password when it wakes up.

Comment: Forgot to mention I don't want to enter my password after every wakeup from sleep, I'll update my post.

Comment: @newenglander In that case, don't check the "Require password [immediately] after sleep or screen saver begins" - the first part of your question also explicitly states you want to "lock my mac"

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Daniel L. was kind enough to update my question, hopefully now it's clearer.

Comment: The third key in that shortcut renders as unprintable for me in Chrome, for some reason. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: @DanJ It's the eject key. Odd though, I'm using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 and Lion 10.7.3 and it looks fine here.